# Export to xls in customised way

Tags: php, excel

My application is fetching a data dynamically from MYSQL and displaying. The Problem is even i have to give the option to "Export to Xls" file. And these file should be in a A4 size, so i should customize the font size of contents in the Xls file to fit into the A4 size.And i need to insert if possible image into the file.

Please help me to solve this as i am new to php and need to complete it within a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- [PHPexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) or
- [PEAR_Spreadsheet_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected)
- [php_excel extension](http://github.com/iliaal/php_excel) by [Ilia Alshanetsky](http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) <sup>(this requires a commercial license for [libXL](http://www.libxl.com/))</sup>

to create the Excel Sheets.